Firebase Hosting : Next.js with Custom App (Cannot access routes and pages)
I am trying to deploy a basic Next.js application on Firebase Hosting. The same runs as expected in a local environment (npm run dev/build) and firebase emulator (firebase emulators:start).
When I deploy the application via firebase deploy --only hosting the application deploys successfully in firebase. However, I cannot reach the custom routes anymore.
I am using the standard documentation approach to override the App component:
_app.js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

Despite working in a local environment and firebase emulator, I cannot get it working in firebase hosting and I and up with "404: This page could not be found." .
Do you have any suggestions on how to debug this further ?
Reference:
next.config.mjs

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export'
}
export default nextConfig;

firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5004
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
  
  
}

